# mmqgis python error message

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, mmqgis

I uploaded the mmqgis plugin to merge layers together, but when I tried to open mmqgis> combine> merge layers there is a python error message. Details read, "AttributeError: 'QListWidget' object has no attribute 'findText'"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/VolAero/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_menu.py", line 316, 
   in merge dialog = mmqgis_merge_dialog(self.iface)

  File "C:/Users/VolAero/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 1714, 
   in __init__mmqgis_load_combo_box_with_vector_layers(self.iface, self.sourcelayers, True)

  File "C:/Users/VolAero/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 2610, 
   in mmqgis_load_combo_box_with_vector_layers combo_index = combo_box.findText(layer.name())

AttributeError: 'QListWidget' object has no attribute 'findText'
```

Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  When does the error occur?  As soon as you open the plugin, or after you enter some info?

Comment: Which version of MMQGIS are you using?

Comment: To help the subject, a little info :I have the same error message when I launch the tool. I'm using QGIS 2.18.4. Same error message starting with "AttributeError: 'QListWidget' object has no attribute 'findText' ". this message seems to indicate the same type of error and some hints to solve it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933763/getting-listwidget-item-text-and-image-in-pyqt

Comment: I had this, as previously comment which was deleted. For me this worked. Ensure no layers are selected. Then go to menu and create merge. Change the temp save to something else on local drive. Hope this resolves for you

Comment: It works with your method, @mappingdom !

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can also use "Merge vector layers" in the Processing Toolbox. (QGIS geoalgorithms/Vector general tools/Merge vector layers) or via the search box.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked.

- Ensure coordinate systems are the same.
- Make sure **nothing** is selected in the layers panel.
- Then launch merge from the menu and select the layers.

Save the output to what you want. I'm running on;

Mac

QGIS version 2.18.2
Compiled against Qt 4.8.6
Compiled against GDAL/OGR 2.1.2
Compiled against GEOS 3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1
PostgreSQL Client Version 9.4.9
QWT Version 6.1.3
QScintilla2 Version 2.9.1

MMGIS version; Installed version: 2017.2.28

Comment: The "nothing selected" seems to solve the problem on my computer.

Comment: Glad to hear as @gisnside notes this looks like a bug, hopefully this feeback can help pin point it

Comment: You are @gisnside . i need another coffee!